# Does noise model in qiskit impact the optimized parameters for QAOA?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, simulation, noise, qaoa

I have read this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.02196.pdf) about the effects of quantum noise on QAOA.

In the conclusion, it says: QAOA is a noise-tolerant algorithm, quantum noise does not change the QAOA quantum circuit parameter optimization direction, for both noisy and ideal QAOA cost functions, the optimized QAOA parameters being nearly the same.

I use qiskit to perform some experiments. Basically, I add a noise model to the simulator during the parameter training process. I found that, the optimized parameters are different when I use `qasm_simulator` and `COBYLA`. However, when I use `statevector_simulator` and no matter which optimizer, the optimized parameters are exactly the same with and without noise model.

I know that for `statevector_simulator`, there is no sampling noise. Is the difference of the optimized parameters caused by the sampling noise for `qasm_simulator`? Will the noise model impact the value of the optimized parameters theoretically?